# Magento - Exclude products with no image from list - Unknown column small_image

Tags: magento, filter, product

ref: template/catalog/product/list.phtml
I am trying to filter all products from the Magento list with no images. I have added the following to $productCollection:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('small_image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
```

I am getting the following error:
a:5:{i:0;s:2550:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.small_image' in 'where clause'

```
- The small_image column is included in catalog_product_flat
- I have re-indexed.
- $_product->getSmallImage() returns correctly - image URL or no_selection
```

Answer (score 0):

on product collection `->addAttributeToFilter('image', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))` try this instead of `small_image`.

Comment: Tried this and does not work. However, this does not throw any error message - which is strange as image is not included in catalogue_product_flat.  If I turn off product flat in the back end then all is fine but I would prefer to have both flat and non-flat options working.